# Explicit solutions to $x^y=y^x$ using Lambert $W$

Tags: exponential-function, inverse-function, lambert-w, piecewise-continuity

A Flammable Maths video gives the solutions to the title equation by $y=-\frac{x}{\ln x}W(-\frac{\ln x}{x})$. This makes a lot of sense, given that Wikipedia gives $W_0(-\frac{\ln x}{x})=-\ln(x)$ for $x<e$ and $W_{-1}(-\frac{\ln x}{x})=-\ln(x)$ for $x>e$, resulting in the trivial solutions on $y=x$. What I'm interested in is the following:

- Is there a way to get the other solution, i.e. $y=-\frac{x}{\ln x}W_0(-\frac{\ln x}{x})$ for $x>e$ and $y=-\frac{x}{\ln x}W_{-1}(-\frac{\ln x}{x})$ for $x<e$, without a piecewise function?
- Can this be simplified to a nice expression in a similar way to the $W$ $ln$ simplification of the trivial solution?

Comment: This isn't a direct answer to your question, but you might be interested in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/793755/81360) as well

Comment: That polar solution is really interesting, thanks! The other solutions come back to this function, though, and I'd still like to see if there's a simplification here :)

Comment: I suspect that the answer to this question is something like the following: when extracting a solution for one variable in a relation like this, we always have to make some "ugly" separations or piecewise approaches. I think that an (easier) equation whose solution follows a similar process is 
$$
x-y = (x+y)^2
$$

Comment: So there is no solution to the second point either? i.e., there is no way to simplify $W_0(-\frac{\ln x}{x})$ for $x>e$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there analytic solution to $x^y=y^x\land x\neq y$ as $y(x)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/617589/is-there-analytic-solution-to-xy-yx-land-x-neq-y-as-yx)

Comment: @JeanMarie it does not; I've already arrived to the same answer as that post, but am looking for a further simplification; after Omnomnomnom's point, I'm basically looking for a simplification of $W_0(-\frac{\ln x}{x})$ for $x>e$.

Answer (score 1):

Another parametric solution in terms of $a>0$ is

\begin{align}
x&=a^{1/(a-1)}
,\\
y&=a^{a/(a-1)}
=a\,x
.
\end{align}